# Asp.Net MVC + AngularJS, should I still pass model to View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I'm learning AngularJS and playing with mixing it with ASP.Net MVC. I'm wondering, should I still pass model from MVC controller to the View and then load it to Angular model? Or should I just open View without model and request data needed by $http by AngularJS? What is the preferable approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should request data from AngularJS to your own controller or api, its not good practice to load all data at once with model, but part by part that is needed.

For example if you have a 1000 pages, and user comes to your website it's not good to load data for all 1000 pages. Its much better to load data for pages that user wants to see.

Comment: what if I have a list of 10 strings + another list of 5 strings? should I still request it form Angular?

Comment: Same, you need to create your own API, and use it to retrieve data.
you can either create one large request to get all information for that page, or you can split it to several smaller request that's up to you to decide which approach you want to go with.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was really confused, what to do.

Comment: I did this site https://www.vegaitsourcing.rs/ you can take a look at request, this is case where all page data is retrived in one request.

Comment: It looks very good and is fast. Will study your requests, thanks again